# Programmatically add a border to WKInterfaceGroup - Solved

Tags: objective-c, watchkit, watchos-5

Is it possible to give a WatchKit table cell or WKInterfaceGroup a border width of 2px and a red border color? If not, are there any work-arounds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can't be done programmatically, but you can give the impression of a boarder in IB.

Add a separator above and below the cell's sub-group.

[image: Add a separator above and below the cell's sub-group.]

Give the cell's main group a background color.

[image: Give the cell's main group a background color.]

Make the first separator an alpha of 0 and a top vertical alignment.

[image: Make the first separator an alpha of 0 and a top vertical alignment.]

Give the cell's sub-group a center vertical alignment.

[image: Give the cell's sub-group a center vertical alignment.]

Give the second separator an alpha of 0 and a bottom vertical alignment.

[image: Give the second separator an alpha of 0 and a bottom vertical alignment.]

I'm pleased with the result.

[image: I'm pleased with the result.]